# import AWS lambda layer for pymysql

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pymysql, aws-lambda-layers

I need to deploy a lambda function carrying out a process with the python package pymysql, my python version is 3.6 and for this purpose I will use the lambda layers to avoid bring my whole code. In order to achieve this I have follow the steps below:

- create in my local machine a python virtualenv
- install the pakcage pymysql
- create a separate folder where I move the pymysql package installed in my virtual env `cp -r /myvirtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql ~/home/user/packagelambda/`
- within the path `~/home/user/packagelambda/` compress this package into a zip file to be uploaded as AWS lambda layer `zip -r rdsconnection.zip *`
- upload this zipfile as new layer into aws lambda dashboard

Once I complete the process above , I went to my code and create two scripts to modularize my execution , a first script called **md_conenction.py** as below:

```
import json
import boto3
import pymysql 
import csv
from datetime import datetime


def json_param():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucketname= "bucket"
    file= "file.json"
    object= s3.Object(bucketname,file)
    body = object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf8')

    param= json.loads(body)

    return param["host"], param["user"], param["password"], param["database"]

def db_connection():

    host,user,password,database = json_param()

    dbconnection = pymysql.connect(host,user,password,database)
    dbcursor = dbconnection.cursor()

    return dbconnection, dbcursor
```

Additionally a secon script in lambda functions by default called **lambda_function.py** with the content below:

```
import json
from md_connection import db_connection

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    dbconnection, dbcursor = db_connection()
    print(dbcursor)


    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Finally I when to my layers option on the designer and appends the new layer built previously. Once complete this process I still keep on getting the error `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pymysql'` after every execution.

I would like to highlight that I have tried to carry out the process building a layer in two ways:

1. just including the package downloaded by python `pymysql`
2. including two folders after the package installation `pymysql` and `PyMySQL-0.9.3.dist-info`
3. I include runtime compability for Python 3.6 and up to python 3.8 upon layer building

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a directory `python` copy `pymysql` and its dependency into the directory. Zip the `python` directory and upload it to the layer. The folder structure inside the zip  matters. The root directory should be `python`

Comment: what you mean is that I have to follow an structure within the zip file uploaded in my layer? example: rdsconnection.zip contains the structure python/pymysql ?

Comment: Yes. The root folder should be `python` and under that you can add the library like `python/pymysql`

Comment: let me try this sr